# Partition Key Question

Tags: linq, azure, azure-table-storage

Let's I define my entity like this:

```
public class User : TableServiceEntity
{
    /// <summary>Unique Id (Row Key)</summary>
    public string Id
    {
        get { return RowKey; }
        set { RowKey = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the username (Partition Key)</summary>
    public string Username
    {
        get { return PartitionKey; }
        set { PartitionKey = value; }
    } 
}
```

will the following Linq query use the partition key or not?

```
var ctx = ServiceLocator.Get<UserDataServiceContext>();
return ctx.Users.Where(x => x.Username == Username).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure it will not.  You can verify this with Fiddler however.  If you do not see a $filter on the wire with PartitionKey and RowKey in it, then you are not querying by them (which is probably bad).  I believe what you will have on the wire is an entity that has 4 properties (PK, RK, Id, and Username) and the properties that you will be querying on will not be indexed.

Comment: The property access to the base class property is present in the Linq expression tree presented to the driver. So it all depends on how clever the driver is. But I agree the chances are pretty slim :)